# Why are the SPFx web parts NOT working in one of the three tenants?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, site-settings

*The five web parts needed to build the Luminas SP site are having issues with the external linking or security/settings, or maybe its just the app catalog?*

I deployed five web parts in two separate tenants. They were my personal SPO tenant, and a co-workers personal SPO tenant. They worked with no errors. Then I tried a third office 365 tenant. The third tenant,'luminas1' had the five web parts installed in the app catalog by one of their workers. I then go to the Luminas SP site. I see the five web parts when I add a web part to a modern page. They are all there to be selected. I select each of them, and I get the "something went wrong" message and when I open the technical details, I receive the errors below on the page:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
I am an external user and was granted full control. But I was not given the rights to build an app catalog. I don't know for sure, but SharePoint is not friendly to external users. I had to direct a worker in that company. With 'luminas1' tenant, we were able to build an app catalog, and paste the web parts in the catalog. The directions were from Microsoft, so maybe she didn't follow them well.

*I suggest we rebuild the app catalog, reinstall the web parts, check the publisher settings, external linking settings, security, or other settings. There has to be some settings, or external linking and security issue.*

In Luminas, I can see the new web parts on the pages, all of them. So it would lead me to think they were deployed. Here is the calendar, one of the five web parts: 
[image]

There has to be a bug somewhere or a setting issue?

Comment: I would guess the app catalog is shared with "Everyone except external users" - which won't include your user.

Comment: Ah yes, that could be it...How do I include an external user? Is there a setting, or some way to add external users?

Comment: Just like the mentioned group, there is one simply called "Everyone". This group can be given read access to the whole site. There is also another site level setting that says if the site can be shared externally, this can be checked in SharePoint Admin Center.

Comment: I will try that, and keep you posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I needed an account on the tenant domain** - It turns out that for SharePoint Online at least you need an account on the domain to access and use the web parts. I am using a persons account who has left the company and I can see the web parts and have no trouble. 
As an external user, I could not use the web parts but now I can.